# Users not registering in phpmyadmin localhost DB

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgqVNMTnmDQ) and everything seems to be going fine (for the most part), but whenever a user is created, it redirects to the welcome page showing as if everything happened correctly, but then I check my phpmyadmin DB and there is nothing recorded...

I have this as my connect line to access the DB:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password', 'social');
```

and then once the user has entered all information and hits `submit` this action should take place?

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$pswd2','$d','0')");
die("<h2>Welcome to SOCiAL</h2>Login to your account to get started....");
```

where `social` is the name of the database in phpmyadmin, and `users` is the name of the table. It's probable that I have something horribly wrong here but I'm new at this and have no idea what I'm doing, hence watching the tutorial. Let me know if there is something else you need to see, thanks!

EDIT:

This is what was provided as the SQL code to set up the `users` database in phpmyadmin.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`sign_up_date` date NOT NULL, 
`activated` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Also, I've manipulated a little bit of it to Mysqli since I was getting errors before as well..just FYI

Answer (score 0):

You did a mistake.. You inserted `$pswd2` though you haven't created the column for that.. Your query should be like this :

```
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$d','0')");
die("<h2>Welcome to SOCiAL</h2>Login to your account to get started....");
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that. However it will still not copy over to the database.

Comment: did you check the connection configuration?

Comment: `$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'social');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}` Run this and check if the script is showing any error.

Comment: check your php script for errors like variable name and others.. Providing the php script before insertion query would have been better